# Scrapy close after 2 minutes running

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to monitor webpage to find available products and I use scrapy framework.
If I found a product I'll notify it. 
This webpage has in main page the list of product with some information about them and other information in product page.

```py
class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'productpage'
    start_urls = ['https://www.productpage.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.css('article'):

            link = 'https://www. productpage' + product.css('a::attr(href)').get()
            id = link.split('/')[-1]
            title = product.css('a > span::attr(content)').get()

            price = product.css('a > figure::text').get()

            product = Product(self.name, id, title, price, image, size, link)
            yield scrapy.Request('{}.json'.format(link), callback=self.parse_product, meta={'product': product})

        yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
        # The program pass this line and after some minutes it closes without error

    def parse_product(self, response):
        product = response.meta['product']
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        product.image = jsonresponse['images'][0]['small_url']

        for size in jsonresponse['available_sizes']:
            product.size.append(u'{} | {}'.format(size['name'], size['id']))

        send(product)
```

why the program go through this line?

```
yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

Comment: Please show your log output

Comment: @gangabass there is no log output, it closes without error or anything else

Comment: Try this command `scrapy crawl productpage > Debug.txt 2<&1`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. I’ve simply added `yield scrapy.Request(response.url, dont_filter=True)` to the `parse` callback of the default spider generated by `scrapy genspider example.com`, and it works.